# ExcelJS: The library does not respect column width while positioning images

Tags: javascript, exceljs

I'm using ExcelJS library to align an image in my excel. Column Widths are set before hand. for example, A column has width 60.

When I try to add an image starting from 50% of A's column width, Excel JS still takes the default original width and not the new width that is applied.

```
ws.getColumn('A').width = 60;

ws.addImage(imageId, {
  tl: { col: 0.5, row: 0.5 },
  ext: { width: 100, height: 100 },
});
```

[image]

In the above image, the image should start from 50% of column A. Am I missing something or the library fails to understand that a default width has been applied?